# Alternative routing for MVC WebAPI - Can route config concatenate /this/withThis/ to form the action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm at the design stage of creating a web-api that retrieves data from a database with the idea that the web-api will cover all data use cases supposing the database schema doesn't change but new applications will come along to access it. Essentially CRUD for every table.

The database design is extremely normalised for example a 'Person' table has a relationship to the PersonEmail and PersonPhone tables that actually store the data as there is no limit on the number of emails or phone numbers associated with a given person.

With this in mind, I thought the web-api should look like this:

```
/api/Persons/                         //Gets all persons details
/api/Persons/<ID>                     //Gets specific person details
/api/Persons/<ID>/Emails/             //Gets specific person's email addresses
/api/Persons/<ID>/Emails/Add          //Add email to a specific person
```

While this might look unusual I think it has advantages in being very easily understood and allows applications to 'dig down' by providing more parameters to retrieve more specific results. It also allows for additional options to be added at the end such as (only current vs historical or only primary).
Compare the two:

```
/api/Persons/<ID>/Email?primary=true // Preferred
/api/Persons/<ID>/GetPrimaryEmail/   // Seems like it could get out of hand
```

However the web-api routing config doesn't seem to cater for this easily. 
I understand one work around would be to have HEAPS of routes configured such as:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PersonEmailApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/Persons/{id}/Email/Add",
    defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "AddEmail" }
);
```

This is messy and undesirable. Is there anyway to easily handle a web-api structured in this way? Or maybe a few tricks to simplify it a bit, for example is it possible to form the action by concatenating /Add/ with /Email/?

Thanks for reading, please comment if you have other ideas

Comment: Have you looked at attribute routing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2  You seem to imply that it'll be messy to define all the routes in code.  This is not needed.

Comment: You might also be interested in looking into using OData....  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'm going to read about both these suggestions now (@BrendanGreen @Dan-Field)

Comment: Here are 2 options: 1) Use .NET Reflection to scan your controllers and actions for methods that match your specific patterns and use them to build your routes on the fly 2) Create a custom IHttpRoute that converts your convention-based URLs into route values and route values back into convention-based URLs. Attribute routing doesn't really solve anything here if what you are trying to do is avoid maintenance overhead.